# Fullcalendar window is automatically scrolling up

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar, semantic-ui

I've got an issue with creating new events. In Chrome for example, scroll down the to the bottom, make sure it's height is small enough, so you cannot see the whole calendar.

Click buttons **month**, then **week**, then **month**, **week** (several times). Now try to create an event today at 11pm - a modal window will appear. Press Cancel.

What I get now and what is wrong - browser window is scrolled up, until the Title of the calendar!

As you see - there is no my own libraries included, only basic code from fullcalendar/semantic-ui documentation.

The issue doesn't happen with Semantic-ui modal window itself (without fullcalendar). Moreover, just after a page refresh everything is Ok, but then pressing month/week/month/week enables this scrolling up.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    header: {
      right: 'month,agendaWeek'
    },
    aspectRatio: 1.8,
    selectable: true,
    select: function() {
      $('.ui.modal').modal('show');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://fullcalendar.io/js/fullcalendar-2.2.5/fullcalendar.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://fullcalendar.io/js/fullcalendar-2.2.5/lib/moment.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://fullcalendar.io/js/fullcalendar-2.2.5/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/1.11.1/semantic.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/1.11.1/semantic.min.css">

<div style="height:1000px;"></div>
<div id="calendar"></div>
<div class="ui small modal">
  <div class="actions">
    <div class="ui black cancel button">Cancel</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

JSFiddle example: https://jsfiddle.net/edomzxLL/1/

Please help me to understand what's wrong and how to prevent this strange/unneeded scrolling up?

---

**EDIT:**

At the moment I think it's done by a modal window. There is a code, which runs when window closes:

```
...
onComplete : function() {
  settings.onHidden.call(element);
  module.restore.focus();
  callback();
}
...
```

... **onHidden()** is fired and then focus returns to the last focused object. That's an issue. If I have a focused element somewhere in the beginning of a webpage, then scroll down, show a modal window and close it - browser is automatically scrolling up to the beginning of the page to that focused element. Commenting out this line helps me, but this is editing a Semantic source code, which is not a solution. In my case probably button gets a focus.

Comment: A fiddle is always welcome, but please ensure you include the relevant code in the question too. If jsFiddle had gone down (as it frequently does) your question would be unanswerable, and useless to any future visitors.

Comment: your snippet is not working for me. can you provide a working example?

Comment: @AlexanderTyapkov, not working at all or without auto scrolling up? It works everywhere for me where I try. Did you scroll the window until the bottom first? Is window's height small enough so you cannot see the whole calendar? Have you pressed month/week/month/week buttons several times? Last question is very important. Only after these operations try to create an event

Comment: @Alexey ok, I tried to follow your scenario. When I create event and click Cancel the windows doesn't scroll up. (Firefox 58, Ubuntu) Probably the issue is browser specific?

Comment: @AlexanderTyapkov, in Firefox I have similar issue. Tried VM with Win 10 - same thing with MS Edge

Comment: @Alexey Yes, I can confirm that issue exists. I have tried to open in IE with browserling. However, have no idea how to catch the error without opportunity to reproduce it in local environment.

Comment: @AlexanderTyapkov, I've added an EDIT to the post, my latest thoughts on what can be the problem

Comment: I have the same problem, the client is very pissed off, but unfortunately don't have good looking solution for now, apart from editing the code... 
I hope this will be fixed soon.

Answer (score 3):

set `scrollTimeReset` prop to `false`:
https://fullcalendar.io/docs/scrollTimeReset

Comment: this should be the selcted answer. it's the right solution for auto scroll when the focus is moved from calendar to other object.

Answer (score 0):

```
 const calendar = new Calendar(calendarEl, {
  timeZone: 'UTC',
  plugins: [interactionPlugin, dayGridPlugin, timeGridPlugin, listPlugin],
  headerToolbar: { left: 'prev,next', center: 'title', right: '' },
  initialView: calendarView,
  eventDurationEditable: true,
  slotDuration: `00:${duracaoMinimaConsulta}`,
  locale: 'pt-br',
  navLinks: true,
  editable: true,
  dayMaxEvents: true,
  dateClick: handleDateClick,
  eventClick: handleEventClick,
  eventResize: handleResizeEvent,
  eventDrop: handleDropEvent,
  **scrollTime: scrollTime, (Set this property)** Ex.: scrollTime: "20:00"
  events: eventosState,
});
```

Comment: HI :) Welcome
Have you tested this?

Comment: Yes. I am using FullCalendar on React Project @WurmD.

Answer (score -1):

I really don't understand the issue.

The first div in your document has a height of 1000px so obviously the rest of the document flows down.

When you open your modal it has a height and width of 100 % so scrolling up is disabled.

Comment: This seems more like a comment than an answer.

Comment: @Enrico, the issue is not with disabled scrolling when modal window is open, but with **automatical** scrolling up when it is closed

Comment: Additional div with a height of 1000px is to see this scrolling up easier

Comment: It doesn't scroll up on my device (Win 10 - Chrome Canary). When the modal is closed the calendar is still positioned where it was. I tried to add events in the week tab, swapping from months to weeks, etc, it always stays in place.

Comment: It does for me, Linux + Chromium/Firefox. Did you scroll the window until the bottom first? Is window's height small enough so you cannot see the whole calendar? Have you pressed month/week/month/week buttons several times? Last question is very important. Only after these operations try to create an event

Comment: Yes I did @Alexey, every time I close the modal I'm still at the bottom of the screen.

Comment: Tried on my Win 10 VM in VirtualBox, still scrolls up, so probably it's not because of different environment with you